# Extract button Id or label when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates

My template has a series of buttons in this format:

```
<button class="button button1" onclick="showAlert(xxx)">Button 1</button>
<button class="button button2" onclick="showAlert(xxx)">Button 2</button>
...
<button class="button buttonN" onclick="showAlert(xxx)">Button N</button>
```

A few lines after those, I want to display this text:

```
<h2>Button {{x}} was clicked</h2>
```

How do I go about implement the Javascript function `showAlert`? I am not familiar with Javascript that much. And what can I put in the variable `{{x}}` to achieve this alert? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ES6 (More up to date JavaScript) to solve this.
Don't forget to check it in IE for compatibility. If it doesn't work then you can Google *"forEach alternative IE 9"* etc.

This way you can still output all buttons in another loop and just use the "increment" value for the `id`.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
let outputText = document.getElementById('btn-num');

buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', event => {
   outputText.innerText = `Button ${event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id')} was clicked`;
  })
})
```

```html
<button class="button button1" data-id="1">Button 1</button>
<button class="button button2" data-id="2">Button 2</button>
<button class="button button3" data-id="3">Button 3</button>
<button class="button button4" data-id="4">Button 4</button>

<h2 id="btn-num">Please click a button...</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have been helpful

```js
function showAlert(x) {
    var y = document.getElementById('resText');
    y.innerText = 'Button ' + x + ' was clicked'
}
```

```html
<button class="button button1" onclick="showAlert('B1')">Button 1</button>
<button class="button button2" onclick="showAlert('B2')">Button 2</button>
<button class="button buttonN" onclick="showAlert('BN')">Button N</button>

<h2 id="resText"></h2>
```